# Testing SEO website

Tags: seo, testing

I have a web application in ASP.NET MVC that we want SEO optimized. I wanted to test whether the pages are appearing as search results in Google. However, I didn't want it to appear to the general public until I am ready to go live. Is there a way to do a sandbox testing of an SEO website on Google where I can continue developing and testing without it being pop up for search results for everyone else?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Such a sandbox can't even exist. Google ranking takes lot of user behavior into account which won't be possible without showing it to users. Also, if G provide such a sandbox, it would be best place to reverse engineer google's algo.

Comment: Long answer: Noooooooooooo.

Answer (score 3):

here is a list of some web tools, but you can't test them offline:

- Métatag générator
  http://www.outils-referencement.com/outils/pages-web/balises-meta
- robot.txt generator
  http://robots-txt.com/
- W3C Validator
  http://validator.w3.org/
- CSS Validator
  http://jigsaw.w3.org/
- Accessibility Validator
  http://wave.webaim.org/
- Website tester
  http://www.webpagetest.org/
- Page speed test
  https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights
- Google analytics
  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced
- Google webmaster tools
  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/
- Bing site register
  http://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url
- Bing webmaster tools
  https://www.bing.com/webmaster/home/
- Test server compression
  http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression
- Bots list
  http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/
- SEO Crawler
  http://www.microsoft.com/web/seo/
  http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/
  http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html
  http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/lnkexam/freeware.htm
- SEO tools (just a bonus you can't believe them all, they are there mainly to make money)
  http://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/checks/seo-checks/
  http://seositecheckup.com/
  http://www.webseoanalytics.com/free/seo-tools/HTML-validator.php
  http://www.seocentro.com/tools/seo/seo-analyzer.html

you can use an IP to make your test (or create a temporrary sub domain), and when you are ready use your real domain name

Comment: You mentioned Google Webmaster Tools https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/
What can one do with it having offline website ?

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of tools out there (remember, they're just tools, no replacement for an expert SEO)  to test if it's optimised. Simply sear for SEO audit tools. You can put the site on a domain (if it isnt already) and make sure it's noindexed via robots text:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

and also put this in your head tags:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

You can then use  alot of audit tools for info on semantics, markup, other metas etc.

Comment: The `robots`meta hasn't been usefull for quite some time now :)