# Theme load speed - do a few seconds matter?

Tags: google, page-speed, load-time

Here’s a questions for the devs and SEO guru’s … If we are looking at themes to help speed up the front end dev and design time on certain projects do we need to take into consideration the load speed times? Google states that it should be 3 secs though all of the themes I have checked are coming in at 5 sec +. I know other things are taking into consideration, like accessibility, quality of code, responsiveness, keywords, etc. so is it such a big deal if the load is slightly longer? Thoughts

Also - Can anyone recommend a reliable speed test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tests

- https://gtmetrix.com/
- http://www.webpagetest.org/

Speed is important - every second costs money. Every second of delay in page loading time can result in a 7% decrease of online sales.

[image]

Comment: great picture mate!

Comment: very helpful - cheers for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the Google page speed insight : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=fr

If you want more tool, i posted some in this post : [Testing SEO website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86483/testing-seo-website/86491#86491)

Comment: With respect, this does not answer the question. Can you please add a blurb to answer the question?? Thanks in advance.